# Limit Rendering Speed

Tags: performance, rendering, limit

I have this method here which renders my players movement.  It swaps between 3 images, standing, left leg forward, and right leg forward.

It swaps images very fast so how can I change the speed of the rendering?

```
public static void renderUpwardWalking() {
    ImageIcon[] frames = { CharacterSheet.up, CharacterSheet.upLeftLeg,
            CharacterSheet.upRightLeg };

    if (Key.up && Character.direction == "up") {
        currentFrame++;
        if (currentFrame == 3)
            currentFrame = 1;
        Character.character.setIcon(frames[currentFrame]);
    } else if (!Key.up && Character.direction == "up") {
        currentFrame = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure there are better ways, but here's what first comes to mind (albeit a naïve approach): First store `System.currentTimeMillis()` in a variable (e.g. `lastMoveTime`), then, on every call to your move method, compare the current time to the stored time; if enough time has passed, change the image and update the stored time. Adjust to taste.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the scale of your currentFrame counter, and use its range to control your frame rate:

```
 //Let  this go from 1...30
 int currentFrameCounter;


 .
 .
 .
 currentFrameCounter++;
 if(currentFrameCounter == 30) currentFrameCounter = 0;

 //Take a fraction of currentframeCounter for frame index  ~ 1/10 frame rate
 //Note care to avoid integer division
 currentFrame = (int) (1.0*currentFrameCounter / 10.0);
```

Putting it all together in a general model:

```
 int maxCounter = 30; //or some other factor of 3 -- controls speed


 int currentFrameCounter;

 public static void renderUpwardWalking() {
     ImageIcon[] frames = { CharacterSheet.up, CharacterSheet.upLeftLeg,
        CharacterSheet.upRightLeg };

     if (Key.up && Character.direction == "up") {

         currentFrameCounter++;  //add
         if(currentFrameCounter == maxCounter) currentFrameCounter = 0;             
         currentFrame = (int) (1.0*currentFrameCounter / (maxCounter/3.0));  
         Character.character.setIcon(frames[currentFrame]);
     } else if (!Key.up && Character.direction == "up") {
         currentFrame = 0;
     }
```

}

Comment: Works great, but I keep getting an array index out of bounds exception of 3.

Comment: Sorry..you have to ensure that currentFrameCounter remains strictly < maxCounter.  Also, the index gets reset to 0 not 1.  I made the edits.  I ran some test code and my currentFrame stays in [0..2] Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done on timer.

1. Decide on a frame pattern and a frequency. You seem to have chosen the frame pattern CharacterSheet.up, CharacterSheet.upLeftLeg, CharacterSheet.upRightLeg. Let's say you want to swap frame every 400 ms.
2. Get the time from a clock with sufficient resolution. `System.nanoTime()` is usually accurate enough.

`long frameTime = 400L * 1000000L; // 400 ms in nanoseconds`  **Edit**

`currentFrame = (System.nanoTime() / frametime) % frames.length;`

Comment: I am trying to use these variables in my code, but where would currentFrame go?  I tried replacing currentFrame++; however the program yields the same speed as before.  Could you explain this to me?

Comment: I now notice a change in speed by modifying the frameTime however it doesn't seem to be slower.  Any insight?

Comment: Try commenting out all other places where you set the currentFrame variable.

Comment: ` public static void renderUpwardWalking() {
  ImageIcon[] frames = { CharacterSheet.up, CharacterSheet.upLeftLeg,
    CharacterSheet.upRightLeg };
  
  long frameTime = 400L * 1000L; // 400 ms in nanoseconds

  if (Key.up && Character.direction == "up") {
   currentFrame = (int) ((System.nanoTime() / frameTime) % frames.length);
   //if (currentFrame == 3)
    //currentFrame = 1;
   Character.character.setIcon(frames[currentFrame]);
  } else if (!Key.up && Character.direction == "up") {
   //currentFrame = 0;
  }
 }`

Comment: Sorry for my comments.  I don't understand the formatting.  The speed is still fast.  But it looks different.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Works perfect!  Appreciate it :)